# Multi-page application in Silverlight for Windows Embedded 7

Tags: c++, windows, silverlight, embedded

I'm trying to develop an application in Silverlight for Windows Embedded 7, which uses C++.

I was able to run a simple page with a button, which calls another function (a simple Hello world message box).

The great question here is: how can I make a function display another page, defined in another XAML file? All the examples I found online, and even in Microsoft resources, uses a single XAML file with everything done inside it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a student who is suffering from the same problem now. Hope there's someone to help us solve it.

I have searched and found that FRAME is not supported in the SWE.

I have found an alternative way to solve this problem but I'm not familiar with C++ code.
If you knows how to program in C++, would you please read through this and teach me a bit?
Thanks so much.

You can search for"Create a Custom User Control in Silverlight for Windows Embedded".
You'll found a PDF file released by Microsoft.
With this way you can create a custom user control to hold your "multi page".
I have done this step, and with the control I created, I am able to "hide" and "show" it in order to achieve the "multipage" effect.

In my User Control, I have some more buttons to let users to click. However, from the mainpage which hosting the user control, the buttons inside cannot be detect.

In the PDF tutorial they teach how do we call out the methods in the custom control, but I don't understand the C++ code.

If you can get the user control done make the controls in your custom control function correctly, would you please tell me? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To do multi-page applications, you need multiple xaml files. Not sure what the Microsoft tutorials you found were referencing, but i am developing an application now which has more than 20 different pages or screens. You need to design the layouts in XAML/ExpressionBlend and then using event handlers and pointers to the XAMl, implement the views in the C++ source code.

```
// ============================================================================
//  LockDataLogger_Click
// 
//  Description: Event handler implementation
//
//  Parameters:  pSender - The dependency object that raised the click event.
//               pArgs - Event specific arguments.
// ============================================================================
HRESULT MainPage::LockDataLogger_Click (IXRDependencyObject* pSender, XRMouseButtonEventArgs* pArgs)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_NOTIMPL;

    if ((NULL == pSender) || (NULL == pArgs))
    {
     hr = E_INVALIDARG;
    }
  //m_pDeviceSettings_Lang->m_pYear->Focus(false);
  if(m_pDeviceSettings_Lang)
   {
    m_pDeviceSettings_Lang->m_pYear->SetIsDropDownOpen(false);
   }
   m_pLoginScreen->SetVisibility(XRVisibility_Visible);
   m_pLogin_Password->SetPassword(L"");
   m_pHome_LoginOptions->SetVisibility(XRVisibility_Collapsed);
   return hr;
}
```

So this is an event handler implementation for when you clock the "Lock" button on the home screen of my device. All you need to do is name your different pages/menus accordingly and based on event handler implementations, using points, set/change the visibility of the different pages. Very straightforward and hope the example code provides some insight.